# SQL Server 2012 - Reduce 12 Union All into one Query with a Custom Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 question regarding UNION All. I have included the code. I apologize for the terribly coding practice. Still new at it.

Basically, in the source table, there is no date field, but a Product Number field. I need to see the Product Number appear once for each date, going 14 days back from today.

The Date column in this case, has to be a Custom column created by myself. The only way I was able to make it work was to do a Union All then increase with 1 day for each query to get the records I needed which was the Product Number to appear one time for each date. In short, each Product Number should show 14 different times.

Curious if there is another way to write this without doing stored procedures or creating tables.

```
select Product_Number

            ,cast(GETDATE() -1 as date) DateKey
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -2 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -3 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -4 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -5 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -6 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -7 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -8 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -9 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -10 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -11 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -12 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -13 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
      union all
      select Product_Number
            ,cast(GETDATE() -14 as date) 
      from Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
      Where ACTIVE = 'Y'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.Product_Number, t1.dateField
FROM (
   VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE)), (CAST(GETDATE() - 2 AS DATE)),
          (CAST(GETDATE() - 3 AS DATE)), (CAST(GETDATE() - 4 AS DATE)), 
          ...
          (CAST(GETDATE() - 13 AS DATE)), (CAST(GETDATE() - 14 AS DATE))) AS t1(dateField)
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT Product_Number
   FROM Test.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM
   WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y') AS t2(Product_Number)
```

The above query uses a [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) to create an inline table containing all 14 days going back from today's date. Then with `CROSS JOIN` we can combine these dates with `Product_Number` to get the required result set.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte_rec AS (
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL 
SELECT num + 1 AS num 
FROM cte_rec WHERE num < 15
)
SELECT GETDATE() - num AS date, p.Product_Number 
FROM cte_rec
CROSS APPLY PRODUCT_MASTER_0001_PM p
WHERE p.ACTIVE='Y'
```

Explanation: cte_rec - is recursion to get numbers from 1 to 14.
GETDATE()-number - as usually.
Cross apply will output the dates with each product number.

What is better from answer above - you can easily change the number of days.

Comment: Very useful too indeed, both does what I need. I will save both for future! Thanks for the help and taking the time to assist!